# Flash Builder Prof - Mobile Emulator - White screen of nothing... really annoying

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm building a Flex Mobile application. The Emulator of Flash-Builder 4.5 works fine most the time, but sometimes it only displays a white screen with nothing else. 
- No errors on console. 
- No debugging possible. 
- Application still works when run on device with USB.
- Eclipse restart does not help.
- Problem is fixed after system reboot - that sucks...

Anybody else has the same problem? How can i fix that?

Comment: Did you check for security exceptions, usually nine times out of ten in my case it was that. Some file in a different server getting called  and loaded into my swf file. The player throws an exception when manipulating it. Display is fine, changing it is a no-no. Easy fix, make sure all assets and swf are in the same server.

Comment: Yes, having the exact same problem all the time. Checked FB logs, nothing. Debug mode, nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this problem and realized that it only happened when I had Firefox open.  It has something to do with Firefox preventing Flex from using the version of air needed for flex mobile applications (2.7).  Hope this helps.

- edit:  I just disabled the "FlashFirebug" plugin and I can now have Firefox open when I use the mobile emulator.  Seems as though the emulator and FlashFirebug don't play nice.

Comment: OMG - you are right and it is perfectly reproduceable - with the small difference, that disableing "FlashFirebug" does not work on my machine. I really have to keep Firefox closed... Thats a really ugly Bug!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known Issue: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-32320